# How to retrain pytorch-lightning based model on new data using previous checkpoint

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I'm using the [pytorch-forecasting](https://github.com/jdb78/pytorch-forecasting) library (which is based on pytorch-lightning) for running a TFT model on time series forecasting. My training routine is segregated into three different tasks. At first I perform HPO using optuna, then I do a training+validation, and in the end, a retraining with full data (no validation).

Currently, both training+validation and retraining are happening using fresh models from scratch, so the runtime is quite high. So, I'm trying to reduce the run-time of the whole training routine by trying to leverage incremental-training where I'll load the checkpointed trained model from phase 2 and retrain it for smaller epochs on phase 3.

I have a method `fit_model()` which is used in both training/validation and retraining, but with different args. The core part of my fit() looks something like the following:

```
def fit_model(self, **kwargs):
    ...
    to_retrain = kwargs.get('to_retrain', False)
    ckpt_path = kwargs.get('ckpt_path', None)

    trainer = self._get_trainer(cluster_id, gpu_id, to_retrain)   # returns a pl.Trainer object 
    tft_lightning_module = self._prepare_for_training(cluster_id, to_retrain)

    train_dtloaders = ...
    val_dtloaders = ...

    if not to_retrain:
        trainer.fit(
            tft_lightning_module,
            train_dataloaders=train_dtloaders,
            val_dataloaders=val_dtloaders
        )
    else:
        trainer.fit(
            tft_lightning_module,
            train_dataloaders=train_dtloaders,
            val_dataloaders=val_dtloaders,
            ckpt_path=ckpt_path
        )

    best_model_path = trainer.checkpoint_callback.best_model_path    
    return best_model_path
```

While I call the above method in my retraining phase, I can see the log where it says that it's loading the checkpointed model:

```
Restored all states from the checkpoint file at /tft/incremental_training/tft_training_20230206/171049/lightning_logs_3/lightning_logs/version_0/checkpoints/epoch=4-step=5.ckpt
```

But unfortunately, no further training is happening at phase 3. If I look at the `best_model_path` returned by the method, it has the old checkpoint path from train/validation phase and not from retraining phase. How to resolve this issue?

I'm using the following libraries

```
pytorch-lightning==1.6.5
pytorch-forecasting==0.9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working finally. The key thing to keep in mind here is not to use same number of epochs in both training and retraining. If we're training for x epochs and intend to run the retraining for y more epochs, then max-epochs has to be set to x+y and not y in retraining.